# Aurora Postgres doesn't scale down

Tags: amazon-rds

I am evaluating Aurora Postgres serverless option. I created cluster and setup minimum ACU to 0.5 and max to 2. Even after few days without any load, it does not scale down to 0. What do I need to do ?

Tested without any load on server for few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are  you using Serverless V1 or V2 ? Aurora Serverless V2 don't scale down to zero ACU. Idle Aurora Serverless v2 writers and readers can scale down to the minimum ACU value that you specified for the cluster.

Here is the official documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.html